# creating a template in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have created a .psd file named MyTemplate.psd the has layers set up a certain way. This file's configuration will be the same starting-configuration I will need for making tons of different presentations over the next several weeks. Does anybody know if there is a way I can set things up so MyTemplate.psd become a custom preset/stock type of thing that can't be saved over; something that would appear as an option every time I open Photoshop or go to: File, New. I'm a Photoshop beginner and I'm having trouble finding a way to do this.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom presets can't contain any content - they only contain settings such as image size, colour mode, etc.

There is no special template format in Photoshop. However, you could make the file read only.

In Windows for example, you can right click the psd file, choose Properties, and set the Read-only attribute. Then you will not be able to save over the psd accidentally.